# One can’t test things which one doesn’t know (to) exist

Tags: compounds

I wrote a sentence:

> One can’t test things which one doesn’t know to exist.

My English teacher says that is should be without *to*: *...know exist*.

I know this phrase is part of 'concise English' but I can't explain its grammar. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did your teacher offer any explanation?

Comment: 'We know them to exist' is acceptable as an alternative to 'we know [that] they exist' etc. But 'One can’t test things which one doesn’t know to exist' doesn't sound as natural as the to-less version.

Answer (score 2):

> (a) *One can’t test things which one doesn’t know exist.*
>
> (b) *One can’t test things which one doesn’t know **to** exist.*

Both are correct, but they're derived from different structures.

(a) comes from a relative clause that starts out meaning something like
 - *things [(such that) one doesn't know (that) these (things) exist]*,
and then converts into
 - *things [which one doesn't know exist]*.

(b) comes from a relative clause that starts out meaning something like
 - *things [(such that) one doesn't know these (things) to exist]*,
and then converts into
 - *things [which one doesn't know to exist]*.

Using 'thing' instead of 'things' makes the difference even more obvious:

> (a) '*One cannot test a thing which one does not know exists.*'

versus

> (b) '*One cannot test a thing which one does not know **to** exist.*'

So it is not just the disappearance of a 'to' but a change from conjugated verb form to infinitive verb form! Like 'something which you know is the case' versus 'something which you know to be the case'

This is possible because *know* can take either a *that* clause complement, as in (a), or an infinitive complement, as in (b). The fact that they mean the same thing and are both grammatical is normal; there are always different ways to say anything, and many of them resemble one another because they come from similar -- but not identical -- constructions.

**Executive Summary**: Given two sentences that mean more or less the same thing,
and have very similar structures, the way to bet is that both are equally correct.

Comment: which of these two structures is more common than the other?

Comment: We have got the same thing in French: 'une chose dont vous savez qu'elle existe' versus 'une chose que vous savez exister'. How about if the relative pronoun is left out: 'something you know exists' versus 'something you know to exist'? Does it change anything as to which phrase is more common?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your sentence. Google Books returns more than 40,000 results when searching for "know to exist", among them:

> For we conceive that many things do not exist which we know to exist
>   and many things to exist which we know not to exist.

[The Cambridge Companion to Anselm](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z8zGpbpwRhIC&pg=PA70&dq=%22know%20to%20exist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivvZy1n4bSAhViBcAKHYpYDdoQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22know%20to%20exist%22&f=false)

> In the former sense, when necessity of existence has relation to the
>   existence of other things, it denotes that the supposition of the
>   non-existence of that thing of which necessity is affirmed, implies
>   the non-existence of things which we know to exist.

[Encyclopædia Britannica, Sixth Edition, Volume 13](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ns2mEcVjkKYC&pg=PA676&dq=%22know%20to%20exist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2_6DboIbSAhUnCcAKHf-kCiw4ChDoAQgXMAA#v=onepage&q=%22know%20to%20exist%22&f=false)

> How, exactly, can I refute the skeptical hypothesis that my mind is
>   the only thing that I know to exist?

[The Ego Tunnel: The Science of the Mind and the Myth of the Self](https://books.google.com/books?id=dxNPa41yIwYC&pg=PA145&dq=%22know%20to%20exist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP3_rQoobSAhVpLsAKHfFMDDU4ZBDoAQgiMAI#v=onepage&q=%22know%20to%20exist%22&f=false)

Comment: But the question was "How does *know exist* work?" not "Can I use *know to exist*?" or even "Why can't I use *know to exist*?"

Comment: And I'd argue the actual example given by OP is less idiomatic than your similar-looking examples. Not ungrammatical, though.